# How to search better in App Store

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, search

As an example ...

If I wanted to see all **commercial airplane simulator** games out there, how would I accomplish this without going to see title by title?

http://itunes.apple.com/au/genre/ios-games-simulation/id7015?mt=8&letter=A&page=2#page

As using iTunes I can only see this

[image]

> Is there an **external website / application** that we can easily search what are we looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure if it fits the bill, but a great alternative App Store search app is **[AppShopper](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/appshopper/id387037496?mt=8)**. 
It lets you do far more advanced searches and really helps pick up bargains and special offers too!

Comment: I will try it, but It seams that the search is kind'a iTunes ... :/

Comment: it looks nice though and with the same keywords I really get apps based on commercial airplanes, very nice! Thanks

Comment: Link is now dead?