# Make iOS App Store search stop “helping”

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

Apple’s App Store search function sucks.  Example: I thought (wrongly) an iOS app existed called “cookie” that helps us reduce tracking.  But I can’t tell whether I’m wrong or right, because Apple’s search logic appears to be “cookie is related to candy, so let’s show him everything that mentions candy.  And candy crush is a game, so let’s also show him every other game in the store.”

“Cookie” is not the only search that has been hopeless due to this kind of idiocy, so I wonder if there is a way to filter to what I **actually** asked for.

Comment: I have figured out that “cookie” is MacOS only, but the question itself is still valid.

Comment: Edited to be more clear that the question is not about the app in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS App Store search is provided by Apple and can not be directly changed. The best solution is to use another search engine.

## Filter by Site

Use a [site specific filter](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433) with your preferred search engine. Add `site:itunes.apple.com` to your searches. Try, and refine, the following search:

```
cookie site:itunes.apple.com
```

## App Store Search Engines

Alternatively, use an [iOS app search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837170). These include:

- https://theappstore.org
- http://fnd.io

Comment: These three options are still not very good.  But they are MUCH better than Apple's own search.  Thank you.

Comment: You are right, there are few other good choices for better App Store search right now. Consider providing [direct feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback) to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a webmaster tool `search term site:https://abc.com` for cookie app. Found the app for Mac, https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cookie/id1473091386?mt=12. Went to its developer page via the link at the bottom: https://cookieapp.com

Even if this is not the app you're looking for, it's good to have some idea about the developer to find an app quickly. One can look at google play store; chances are that it exists there, if it is on iOS App Store.

- ["Advanced" App Store search](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117159/advanced-app-store-search?rq=1)
- [How to search better in App Store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22875/how-to-search-better-in-app-store?rq=1)
- https://apps.apple.com/in/genre/ios-productivity/id6007

---

- You can try Ghostery, Adguard, and Firefox focus and even private mode for some tracking protection.
- Also, you can frequently delete website data in settings > Safari > advanced > website data. You would have to log in again, your history remains fine.

Comment: If “appshopper” is still in existence (link fails), it might be an answer.  The rest of this is not.

Comment: see the edited link..

Comment: ?link to a huge collection of apps?  Not much help in fixing the badly broken search function.

Comment: I don’t know why are you adamant to get “no” as an answer. I never done it, but App Store api, if exposes it is a thing worth looking into

Comment: I do frequently delete things from website history.  That doesn’t help overcoming Apple’s extremely bad design for search.